# Want open a plist in NStableview

Tags: swift, plist, nstableview

I've been trying to display a plist file in NSTableView for days. I've read a lot, but so far only found instructions for iOS. My problem is that the individual values ​​are not displayed individually in the NStableView. Only the whole plist file in a cell is always displayed.

I hope someone can help me, because I just can not get any further. I'm still a freshman in Swift.

I uploaded my Plist, if someone can explain me where the error lies.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1t8c4uldwdtp3wk/Archiv.zip?dl=0

```
import Cocoa


class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

@IBOutlet weak var ntext: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var schwarztext: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cyantext: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var magentatext: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var gelbtext: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lightcyantext: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lightmtext: NSTextField!

var n : String? = nil; // n
var schwarz : String? = nil; // Schwarz
var cyan : String? = nil; // Cyan
var magenta : String? = nil; // Magenta
var gelb : String? = nil; // Gelb
var lightc : String? = nil; // Light Cyan
var lightm : String? = nil; // Light Magenta

let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_PATH = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Jobs", ofType: "plist")

let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_N = "n"   // n
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_SCHWARZ = "schwarz"   // Schwarz
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_CYAN = "cyan"   // Cyan
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_MAGENTA = "magenta"   // Magenta
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_GELB = "gelb"   // Gelb
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTC = "lightc"   // Light Cyan
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTM = "lightm"   // Light Magenta

var _jobss = [Jobs]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

    //let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Jobs", ofType: "plist")
    //let myJobs100 = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
    //return myJobs100


    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Jobs", ofType: "plist")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainers, format: nil)

    let dictArray = plist as! [[String:String]]
    return dictArray
}


func allJobss() -> [Jobs]{

    if _jobss.count > 0 {
        return _jobss
    }

    if let allDatas = NSArray(contentsOfFile: AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_PATH!) {

        for dict in allDatas {
            guard let dict = dict as? [String: AnyObject] else {continue}

            let jobs = Jobs()
            jobs.n = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_N] as? String // n
            jobs.schwarz = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_SCHWARZ] as? String // Schwarz
            jobs.cyan = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_CYAN] as? String // Cyan
            jobs.magenta = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_MAGENTA] as? String // Magenta
            jobs.gelb = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_GELB] as? String // Gelb
            jobs.lightc = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTC] as? String // Light Cyan
            jobs.lightm = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTM] as? String // Light Magenta
            _jobss.append(jobs)
        }
    }
    return _jobss
}



func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return allJobss().count
}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(tableView.selectedRow)

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Jobs", ofType: "plist")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainers, format: nil)

    let dictArray = plist as! [[String:String]]
    // [[String:String]] is equivalent to Array< Dictionary<String, String> >

    print(dictArray[tableView.selectedRow]["n"] as Any)



}



override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

}

[NSTableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqMfM.png)

[Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDGb3.png)

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is Swift. Variable names including underscore characters are ugly and *objective-c-ish*.

Your workflow is wrong. `objectValueFor` is called very often (once for each row) and is supposed to return just the object for the given row/column. Reading the same data again and again is horrible.

Load the data **once** in `viewDidLoad` and decode the Plist directly into a class. A class is required to be able to bind the values

```
@objcMembers
class Job : NSObject, Decodable {
    dynamic var n, schwarz, cyan, magenta, gelb, lightc, lightm : String
}
```

---

```
@objc dynamic var jobs = [Job]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Jobs", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    jobs = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Job].self, from: data)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In `objectValueFor` just return the item for the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
     return jobs[row]
}
```

the other delegate methods are

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return jobs.count
}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    let selectedRow = tableView.selectedRow
    if selectedRow == -1 {
       print("Nothing selected")
    } else {
      print("Row \(selectedRow) selected")
    }
}
```

You have to **bind** the values to text fields. Open Interface Builder, <kbd>⌃⇧-click</kbd> on the left-most text field (Table View Cell) in the table view, select **Table View Cell**, press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> to open the Bindings Inspector, click on the disclosure triangle below `Value`, Check the checkbox `Bind to Table Cell View`, in the `Model Key Path` text field write `objectValue.n`. Bind the other text fields in the row to the corresponding properties (`objectValue.schwarz` etc.).

---

You can delete

```
var n : String? = nil; // n
var schwarz : String? = nil; // Schwarz
var cyan : String? = nil; // Cyan
var magenta : String? = nil; // Magenta
var gelb : String? = nil; // Gelb
var lightc : String? = nil; // Light Cyan
var lightm : String? = nil; // Light Magenta

let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_PATH = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Jobs", ofType: "plist")

let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_N = "n"   // n
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_SCHWARZ = "schwarz"   // Schwarz
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_CYAN = "cyan"   // Cyan
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_MAGENTA = "magenta"   // Magenta
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_GELB = "gelb"   // Gelb
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTC = "lightc"   // Light Cyan
let AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTM = "lightm"   // Light Magenta

func allJobss() -> [Jobs]{

    if _jobss.count > 0 {
        return _jobss
    }

    if let allDatas = NSArray(contentsOfFile: AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_PATH!) {

        for dict in allDatas {
            guard let dict = dict as? [String: AnyObject] else {continue}

            let jobs = Jobs()
            jobs.n = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_N] as? String // n
            jobs.schwarz = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_SCHWARZ] as? String // Schwarz
            jobs.cyan = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_CYAN] as? String // Cyan
            jobs.magenta = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_MAGENTA] as? String // Magenta
            jobs.gelb = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_GELB] as? String // Gelb
            jobs.lightc = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTC] as? String // Light Cyan
            jobs.lightm = dict[AUTO_PLIST_JOBS_KEY_LIGHTM] as? String // Light Magenta
            _jobss.append(jobs)
        }
    }
    return _jobss
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now it shows me an error i the line:

let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)  <--- Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL'

Comment: I edited the answer meanwhile to add an `!` at the end of the preceding line.

Comment: Thank you. Now it show me an error in the next line.

jobs = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([Job].self, from: data)  <-- Cannot assign value of type '[Job]' to type '[Jobs]'

Comment: Please use my suggestion to declare the data source array as `var jobs = [Job]()`. A struct is supposed to be named in singular form. Each instance represents one single `Job`.

Comment: I found the problem. I had the struct code in the wrong line. 

Now it starts but show --> tableview.ViewController.Job(n: "13589", schwarz: "1.219", cyan: "0.666", magenta: "0.765", gelb: "3.107", lightc: "8.106", lightm: "7.965") <-- in every cell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TNAH.png

Comment: You have to **bind** to the values to the text fields. I updated the answer. Please (re)read it carefully.

Comment: It works now. I spent a few hours yesterday until I found out the Inspector was the problem. I have a lot to learn :-)